# Codeigniter :Parsing array data in view

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am trying to fetch posts data and past it to view using controller like this

```
 $data['data']=$this->home->fetch_all_posts($this->news);
 $this->load->view('home',$data);
```

in my view when i do print_r($data) this is what i get

```
Array
(


    [0] => Array
        (
            [post] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 65
                    [date] => 2016-07-08
                    [title] =>  title of the news 
                    [content] => content of the news 
                    [type] => news
                )

            [attachments] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [attachment_id] => 65
                    [type] => news
                    [path] => C:/wamp/www/school/ci/images/Jellyfish22.jpg
                )

        )

)
```

now when i try to foreach this and print it does not work , Please helo how can i print these values

Comment: `...and print it does not work`. Ok, what happens?

Comment: pls always be responsive to the answers given , mark it with green check and do upvote if you find it helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

CodeIginiter will turn the values of `$data` into it's own variables. So `$data['foobar']` becomes `$foobar` in the view. Your use of `$data['data']` can be confusing and vague, I'd suggest using a more specific name.

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this**

```
 if (!empty($data)) {
   foreach ($data as $row) 
   {  
     $row['post']->id;
     $row['post']->title;
     $row['attachments']->id;
     $row['attachments']->attachment_id;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

this should be all you need....

```
$array = array(
  array('post'=> array(
           'id' => 65, 
           'date' => '2016-07-08',
           'title' => 'title of the news',
           'content' => 'content',
           'type' => 'news'
           ), 
        'attachments' => array(
           'id'=>2,
           'attachment_id' => 65, 
           'type'=> 'new', 
           'path' =>'C:/wamp'
         ))
  );

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  print_r($value['post']['id']); 
}
```